# How to map kubernetes deployment file values to helm chart values?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Example kube file:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gyselroth/kube-icinga/master/kube-icinga.yaml

I would like to make a helm chart for that, but it seems that helm charts lack structure. I can't just take what's in the yaml file and call it a helm chart. How do pass the contents of that yaml to helm as "helm values"?

I would like to read the docs on this but have been looking for some time now and I can't find documentation. I think I know that for example that  `livenessProbe` belongs under `spec -> containers` in a k8s' `Pod`: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/

But how do I declare a liveness/readiness probe with a helm chart and where is documentation that describes how that's done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the helm chart documentation, with the command you can create a sample template of helm chart, where the values - [link](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_create/) . On the question of probes - [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/)